# Show top level dependencies for a conda managed environment

Tags: python, conda

Just as an example, if I created a new environment.

```
conda install python
conda create --name foo_environment
conda activate foo_environment
conda install python
conda install jupyter
conda env export > environment.yml
```

Very obviously, in this case, there are only two top-level dependencies that are added in this environment: python and Jupiter.

I know that we can export the dependencies according to [Sharing an environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment)

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

But see how verbose it is.

```
name: foo_environment
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - appnope=0.1.0=py37_0
  - attrs=19.1.0=py37_1
  - backcall=0.1.0=py37_0
  - bleach=3.1.0=py37_0
  - ca-certificates=2019.5.15=0
  - certifi=2019.3.9=py37_0
  - dbus=1.13.6=h90a0687_0

...and 70 more lines here.
```

Is there a way to only export the top level dependencies? I know I can manually create the yml file like this below. But doing things manually is a bit annoying. Any way to export the top level dependencies automatically?

```
name: foo_environment
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.7.3
  - jupyter=1.0.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a flag `--from-history` you can use that will only show packages that were explicitly installed and should give you what you want:

```
conda env export --from-history > environment.yml
```

Comment: The history export lacks the versions that were installed, unless they were specified in the 'conda install' commands.  I have not found a way to dump the history-only pkgs with versions.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way of doing this automatically using the `conda` system.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6501) on the `conda` GitHub page that explores a similar scenario (finer control over environment exports). As of 18-06-2019 this issue is open.